# Why the need to use the Futur Antérieur form "aura fallu"?

Tags: conjugaison

> Le voleur **a pu** s’en servir pour descendre le sac d’or. Il lui **aura fallu** un complice qui l’**attendait** en bas.

I’m not sure why the verb "falloir" needs to take the form of the Futur Antérieur "aura fallu" here, especially given how "a pu" and "attendait" strongly indicate a past event. The juxtaposition of *the future and the past*, so to speak, has me puzzled. I’m at a loss how to interpret this sentence.

Is it impossible to use any other conjugated form than "aura fallu" in the given context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look here: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futur_ant%C3%A9rieur_en_fran%C3%A7ais (yeah OK worst source ever, whatev'), you can see four uses:

- Something that will end for sure in the future

  > Il aura terminé ses devoirs dans une heure.
- Something in the future but before another thing

  > Quand j'aurai terminé mes devoirs, je viendrai manger.
- A supposition

  > Il n'est pas encore arrivé ? Il se sera arrêté en chemin.

... equals 'il s'est **probablement** arrêté en chemin', the *futur antérieur* is already a supposition in this use case, and I would add that the probability with the *futur antérieur* is high, it's not *maybe*, it's *probably*. You can still use *peut-être*, *probablement*, *sûrement* to precise the degree of probability, but without any of these words, there is a notion of high probability, in my opinion.

- An assessment, a summary

  > Sa vie entière n'aura été que joie et bonheur.

In your case, it's a supposition with a high probability, but indeed I feel it like it's another case not explained on Wikipédia: since there is a notion of probability in 'a pu', the sentence sounds even more like (not the translation but the meaning):

> If he really used it *(we don't know what 'it' is in your example)* to take the bag, so he needed a partner waiting for him downstairs.

I feel it like: MAYBE he used it (the probability is here), and if so, he NEEDED a partner (no probability, it's a consequence of the first probability if this probability is true).

Comment: Using the **Futur** Antérieur form to make an informed guess about a **past** event. Interesting. Merci.

Comment: ...and since when is wikipedia the *worst source ever* ? I wonder. In my humble opinion, no need for the sidenote, though I didn't dare erase it myself. Your choice, Simon. (by the way, +1 for the overall analysis)